# How to set object in Angular js model list object

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am new to angular js.
I am trying to set a value in object in list object.

```
Model class
public class InfoModel{
    public List<TestInfo> testInfo;
    public void setTestInfo(List<TestInfo> testInfo){this.testInfo=testInfo;}
    public List getTestInfo(){return testInfo;}
    public int amount=0; //we have setters and getters for amount
}

TestInfoclass
public class TestInfo{
    public User user;
    public void setUser(User user){this.user=user;}
    public User getUser{return user;}
}
```

User object has name and id.

```
In angular controller
$scope.submitStatus = function(form1){
    $scope.infoModel.testInfo=[];
    var user; 
    if($scope.infoModel.amount<=6000){
       user = form1[0].user;
    } else {
       user = form1[1].user;
    } //Now I need to assign var user to TestInfo object at 0th location.
}
```

Please help in this. Thanks a lot for your help and time on this.

Thanks 
Rama

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: Java and angular js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var testInfo = {user: user};
$scope.infoModel.testInfo.push(testInfo);
```

This creates a javascript object and add it to the list of testInfos.